# $(A\otimes_k I)^2\simeq A\otimes_kI^2$

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra and $I\subset A$ an ideal. I want prove  that $$(A\otimes_k I)^2\simeq A\otimes_kI^2.$$ Now, of course we have a surjective map from $A\otimes_kI^2$ to $(A\otimes_k I)^2$, bun now I'm not able to go on.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $I^2,$ do you mean $I\oplus I$?

Comment: @Chickenmancer maybe I'm wrong, but usually $I^2=I\cdot I$. In general, for $n\in \Bbb Z^+$, $I^n=I^{n-1}\cdot I$.

Comment: I'm familiar with $I^2=\langle ab\mid a,b\in I\rangle.$ I suppose one might assume  that elementary tensors of the form $a_1\otimes i_1\cdot a_2\otimes i_2=a_1a_2\otimes i_1i_2.$  But if the OP means $I^2$ to be the direct  sum (due to possibly non-standard notation) the result is much simpler in proof.

Comment: I mean exactly that Xam says, i.e. $I^2=I\cdot I:=\langle ab \: : \: a,b\in I\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I think the approach you'd like to take is that  $A^2=A,$ and so defining products of elementary tensors as I did above should produce the necessary isomorphism.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $(A\otimes_k I)^2$? Whwere is the square taken?

Comment: @Mohan, I suppose the OP means to take $A\otimes_k I\subset A\otimes_k A,$ as a $k$ algebra, and then compute the square.

Comment: Considering the tag commutative algebra, I assume $A$ is commutative, in which case I do not see an issue if the square is as described by @Chickenmancer. It is easy to show that both sides are equal to each other (why isomorphism?) as subs of $A\otimes_k A$. Your surjective map (assuming naturally done) is an equality, since both are subsets of the same set.